# enable user interaction by changing alpha swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, animation, alpha, user-interaction

I have a view with the tap function (user interaction is enabled). If I set it without changing alpha it works well. But if I try to change alpha of this view with delay, it cannot be tapped during this animation. Could somebody help?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var myView = UIView()
var n = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setView()
    changeAlpha()

}

func changeAlpha() {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5) {
            self.myView.alpha = 0.1
        }
    }

func setView() {

    let size = view.frame.width
    myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size/3, height: size/3))
    myView.center = view.center
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.addSubview(myView)

    myView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gameObjectTapped(_:)))
    myView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

}

@objc func gameObjectTapped(_ recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    print("# tap \(n)")
    n+=1

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the animation with option `.allowUserInteraction`:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
    self.myView.alpha = 0.1
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried it, but with a slightly changed syntax. Now it works!

Comment: I forgot the brackets (((( UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
    self.myView.alpha = 0.1
}, completion: nil)

Comment: @Roman well, it's all the same.. brackets allow listing more options if you needed them.. anyway, please accept the answer

Comment: Of course, I'll do it. But I have to wait ten minutes (now only two minutes).

Comment: Good answer (voted) although I tend to prefer skipping the brackets  when passing a single OptionSet value. Thus options could be changed to `options: .allowUserInteraction`

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5) {
    self.myView.alpha = 0.1
}
```

to

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0.0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
    self.myView.alpha = 0.1
}, completion: nil)
```